# Unable to import module in PyCharm even though it is installed and is getting imported using shell

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am very new to this. I am working in PyCharm (11.0.4) and I have two versions of Python (anaconda (3.7) and python 3.7 IDLE).

This is the code I am trying to execute: (It's from [Sentdex's](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfzlCWGWYyIQ0aLC5w48gBQ) mini series on web scraping)

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')  # this is a beautifulsoup object
                                         # using the lxml parser
print(source)
print(soup)
```

It was working just fine and beautifulsoup4 is showing in the site packages and the requirement is satisfied. The import works just fine when I run it in the anaconda shell but fails in PyCharm and gives the error: ModuleNotFoundError, It worked just fine when I tried it earlier and I havent changed anything as far as I can recall.

I checked the interpreter and it is using anaconda wherein all these packages are present.

I know this is a frequently asked question but even after trying several solutions mentioned in previous responses nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Check this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html . Also dont get confused by installing Anaconda, Python3.7 and Pycharm. Install anyone and you can start working with it. So for now if any one works fine for you, you can continue using that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not avaliable inside your project folder inside pycharm click on terminal at the bottom left and type inside the terminal

```
pip install bs4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have tried that using the terminal and inside the project folder, but it returns Requirement already satisfied. Moreover I can see the installed package inside the site packages.
What surprises me is that it was working fine yesterday.